# open a pdf from a winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winfors app and need to open a pdf file, this pdf has beed added as a new item in the app directory as show below

[image]

as you can see thepdf file is located in the GFC class library, this is my code

```
private void manualToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ruta = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "manual.pdf");
            string FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "manual.pdf");
            Process.Start(FileName);
        }
```

but got the error

[image]

could you please help me to get the pdf please

Comment: @DourHighArch I imagine that image damage your eyes, if you doesn´t have an answer why do you comment? such a dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try select the file in Solution Explorer. Then you should be able to see its properties in Properties window (press F4 if it is not visible). You will find there two properties:

"Build Action" and
"Copy to Output Directory"
Set "Build Action" to "Content", and then - select an appropriate value for "Copy to Output Directory" setting.

Without doing this, the PDF isn't going to appear in the directory with the compiled application.

Comment: Also tell us the path from the Properties window; it might not be equal to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

Comment: Also, debug your program and take a look at the FilePath value, it should hint you why you're unable to load the file, which chances are, as Ctznkane525 said, that you're not copying the file.

Comment: @DourHighArch if I would known the path I wouldn´t be asking

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can start a process and your default browser or adobe reader will open the PDF.. when it exists !! check your path !! *"no puede encontrar"* etc my translator sais your exception means it can't find the PDF file..

When you would like to have your PDF in a Winforms window, consider using CefSharp mini-browser,

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Quick-Start

This allows for a Chrome-like browser in your application, as a form window. You can load a pdf into the SimpleBrowserForm example.